# WD External HDD Input Output Error,

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, external-hdd, data-corruption

I got the WD My Passport 259F harddisk. After I transferred data onto the harddisk, I clicked "Safely Remove Drive". Perhaps, I removed it too quickly, then when I inserted back, I got the following error:

```
Sorry, could not display all the contents of "9026AC8526AC6E42": Error when getting information for file`. Input/Output Error`
```

However, my system recognizes the Harddisk, it shows up on the windows as "1.0TB Volume". When I click "Properties", it shows 144.5GB is used. I can access data through terminal.

```
$ cd /media/swagatika/9026AC8526AC6E42/
swagatika@swagatika:/media/swagatika/9026AC8526AC6E42$ ls
bin         Extras    WD Apps for Mac      WD Apps Setup.exe
Desktop_Neu_Backup  User Manuals  WD Apps for Windows
```

How can I read it in GUI?

I looked up and tried some other commands, but I am clueless about what should I exactly do to recover the data, I am too afraid to lose it.

Here are some commands I tried:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i -E drdy\|error\|seek
[   14.758946] EXT4-fs (sda4): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

$ dmesg | grep mount
[    3.933130] EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   14.758946] EXT4-fs (sda4): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

$ gnome-disks
```

The screenshot of the output window is given in the following images:

(Internal HD):

[image: Internal HD]

(External HD):

[image: External HD]

Please help me fix this problem and recover the data. Thanks for any help!

Edit: This is the message I get when I plugin my harddisk. After I click OK, I do not see anything on the folder:

[image: Error]

Comment: what are you actually trying to do ? I guess I'm confused... its mounting according to the images .. do you get that error every time you plug it in .. or was it just once? what do  you mean when you say How can I read it in GUI

Comment: I get it every time I plug it in. I want to be able to get rid of the error and see my data in a GUI window. Right now I am able to access data through terminal though, but cannot see anything on GUI.

Comment: @JohnOrion OI tried to use it in windows system. I get a message saying something like "The file system is corrupted and must be formatted".

Comment: still confused .. if you can see and access files in the terminal. I don't understand what you mean by you don't see them in the GUI. What GUI are you talking about .. are you talking about Ubuntu's GUI.. and if so .. then how are you  trying to see them .. what  program are you using?

Comment: @JohnOrion, I updated the question with the screenshot of the error message. After I click OK, I see an empty window and cannot see data.

Comment: When I say GUI, I mean the window on which I am supposed to see the folders.

Comment: ok now i understand ... so sorry it took me so long :( .. but you say when you are in terminal and change directories to `/media/swagatika/9026AC8526AC6E42` you can access the files. If that is the case the easiest way would be to just copy the files out that you want to save off that drive and once you have the files backed up and saved .. you can remove that partition and create a new one  then copy your saved files back to the properly formatted drive again.

Comment: @JohnOrion, Thanks. I just finished copying them back from the external HDD to system. What do you mean by "remove that partition and create a new one"? Do you mean I should format the drive? Can I ensure that there is nothing wrong with the drive?

Comment: well no i would not just format .. i would delete the existing partition and create a new one .. if you want we can start a chat session and I can walk you through the process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39480/discussion-between-swagatika-and-john-orion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through chat we determined this to be a corrupted partition. She was able to access her drive through terminal and knew already how to copy the files he wanted to save

I had her save all the files that were important

We then deleted the existing partition and re-created it

This was able to restore the drive to a working order.

This isn't the greatest "depth" of answer but there was a bunch of troubleshooting and stuff that  would be useless to post.

Answer (score 0):

I do what they said https://askubuntu.com/a/769547/1505994 and I see my files in terminal
I decided to copy my files by command and hope later when I connect my usb to windows system its work
During transfring my files I used `touch` command and next time I clicked on my usb it opened

Comment: What do you mean "I used touch"? Did you touch every file that you copied? [Edit] and clarify.

Comment: `touch` is a command. you can use it to make empty folder in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience. Nemo (a derivative of Nautilus) showed me this message:

> Sorry could not display all the contents of /media/USERNAME/DISKNAME
> Error when getting information for file .cm0013

When I ran `sudo dmesg`, I saw:

> [500734.572421] FAT-fs (sdc1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.

However, I was able to access the files from the terminal using `cd /media/USERNAME/DISKNAME` so I figured that the disk must not be corrupted. I tried creating a new file on the external disk using `touch FILENAME` and it worked. I unmounted the disk, unplugged it and plugged it in again and it worked normally in Nemo. I don't know what was the problem, but I'm guessing that creating a new file in the disk overwrote the bad `.cm0013` file.